# Chromecast tab casting and Java Applet

Tags: google-cast

I am writing a java applet in hopes that my users can use chrome's tab cast to show the applet on a larger screen. However, when I cast the tab, I only see the black background on the TV, even though the applet shows up in the actual browser.

I am using Java web start to launch the applet. Here is my javascript that does that:

```
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script> 
    var attributes = {
    code:'com.gigagrand.CastThat.CastThat',  width:600, height:300} ; 
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'castthat_applet.jnlp'} ; 
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7'); 
</script>
```

I suspect that my problem may lie in how I am launching my applet. Or Tab casting just doesn't support Java Applets

Comment: Even if you car get this to work with Chromecast, I'd strongly advise you to choose a different technology anyway.  Java applets are not supported by any current phones/tablets; and with exploits targeting java in the browser being one of teh most common current methods for malware install a lot of people have disabled/removed the java plugin they installed years ago and forgot about.

Comment: I totally agree with you about the downsides of using Java, however, I am using some native dll libraries in the applet and I don't know of any other language that I can do this with. Do any alternative languages exist?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mirror even if there is an applet running. i.e. Chromecast tab mirroring works for that scenario as well. The only case that you may run into rendering issues is if you try to mirror some protected content running in silverlight on windows.